# Database design help - Splitting out tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am building out an app that have different types of "posts" and a user can insert as many of these as they like. The posts though can be of different types, for example an image post, video post, text post etc... and obviously these will all have different fields in the database. An example would be that the image type will have:

```
Image
----------
date
image_url
```

and the text post might have:

```
Text
----------
date
title
content
```

Now for each of the different types, do I have a unique table and just link the user to these? Assuming this is correct, If I want to show them in date order, do I do this with a `JOIN`, or am I completely on the wrong track.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Why is an image considered a post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural way to model what you're doing here is by mapping an inheritance hierarchy into your relational schema.

What you want is to take all the common elements of all posts (post_id, date_created, user_id, etc.) plus a `type` field and you make that your 'base' table. This table represents all `posts` regardless of the specific kind of post it is.

Next you take all the specific attributes for each type of post and create a table for that specific type (these are the 'children' tables). The primary key of this table is also a foreign key into the base table (post_id).

The `type` field in the base table references which specific table a post belongs to.

So it all ends up looking like this:
[image: Class Table Inheritance]

Now you can do all sorts of queries:

Select all videos, order by descending date:

```
SELECT post.*, video.*
FROM post JOIN video USING(post_id)
WHERE post.type = 'video'
ORDER BY post.date_created DESC
```

Select all posts with just basic details, for a single user:

```
SELECT post.* FROM post WHERE user_id = ?
```

Polymorphic query (Select all post for a single user, with specific type detail):

```
SELECT p.*, i.*, t.*, v.*
FROM post p 
LEFT JOIN image i ON (p.post_id = i.post_id)
LEFT JOIN text t ON (p.post_id = t.post_id)
LEFT JOIN video v ON (p.post_id = v.post_id)
WHERE p.user_id = ?
```

#### The downside, and an alternative

This model gives you great flexibility, but at the cost of greater query complexity and lower query performance. If your videos, text and image posts differ by a small enough number of fields you'll get much better performance by just implementing what some call Single Table Inheritance: a single table that has all the columns for all the subtypes plus a `type` column with the same purpose as above:

[image: Single Table Inheritance]

The key aspect is that the type-specific columns should be nullable (since they will be null for posts which are not of that type). This model is more wasteful in space, but you can run all the same queries as above without needing the child table joins (effectively these tables are already joined by default) resulting in faster, less complex queries.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Will allow for easy scalability as well if I ever want to add more types!

Answer (score 1):

While you could have separate tables for each post type , I cannot think of any reason against using just one table :

> posts

```
post_id
post__type     -- Ex. 1: Text ,2: Image ,3: Video .
post__user_id
post__datetime
post__title    -- Images and Videos probably could have titles as well .
post__content  -- This gets meaning based on post__type . Ex. This would be a URL if post__type is Image or Video .
post__deleted
post__likes_count
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks! I do have a couple of questions though - in terms of speed, is this much quicker than splitting them out and joining them? I am guessing it is.

Also, if I wanted a title **and** a caption on the image/video posts - would this change anything, or do I just add an extra `post__caption` field and null it for the text type posts?

Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: I haven't thought of what factors would affect the speed but I am assuming : Having just one table might be simpler and faster .

Comment: Adding one more `post__caption` for images/videos might not hurt ( where not applicable I would use blank-space rather than null ). I have to mention that my answer is based on the assumption that there will be far many common columns across various post types than post-type specific columns .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would have a table for each type of content with a user id column on each table then when you display the data you write select statements creating joins. Then you can display by date, by user, by date, and content type.

Do some testing using a sqlite database file and test things out before you go into production.